# After installing SQL Server Studio 2017 with Integration and Reporting services, in the Integration Services Catalogs- Create New Catalog shows error

Tags: installation, sql, ssms, ssis, ssrs

SQL SERVER Management Studio 2017 - The error says "The catalog backup file 'C:\SQL\SHARED\X64\140\DTS\Binn\SSISDBBackup.bak" could not be accessed.

Is this error fixing requires "Integration Services" package installed at the SQL SERVER 2017 setup end OR this can be fixed from the SQL SERVER Management Studio 2017? Pls help. I did install SQL SERVER Management Studio 2017 with SSIS, SSAS, SSRS services enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding that "SSISDBBackup.bak" if it exists, right clicking into the properties, unchecking the "Read-Only" properly, clicking "Apply" and "OK".

Very Tedious and Manual Alternative:

1. Try uninstalling everything, clean out all the related regedit
   registries, and clear all the physical files left behind.
2. Manually create the following folder in Explorer.Exe:
   C:\SQL\SHARED\X64\140\DTS\Binn\
3. Install the newest versions of every software and component,
   including drivers, and ensuring that your OS is compatibile